# using multiple encoders in netty channel pipeline

Tags: java, netty

I have to send different types of messages on a netty channel, and these are to be encoded before sending.I am registering multiple `OneToOneEncoder`s in a netty channel , with each `encode` supposed to act on a single type of message. I check the type of msg , encoding if it of correct type for this encoder , or return the msg as such ( with no transforming ) if it is not of the particular type ( of the encoder ). Is this a valid design approach ?

The problem I am facing is : sometimes this leads to various downstream exceptions ( in the decoder ) like IndexOutOfBounds.

What makes it more difficult is that sometimes it works correctly.  I am sure there is something that is getting  messed up in encoding / decoding. what is it exactly eludes me.Any obvious mistakes here ?

edit : my question is about the general design approach .. if that is correct then I can work into bugs in code myself..

Comment: Please paste your code and exception here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have more then one OneToOneEncoder in the ChannelPipeline. Just be sure that these are thread-safe as downstream events can be send from any thread.

Comment: with multiple encoders , will the encode methods be called in a chain ? with the output of one forming the input to another ?